# When and Why would I use Zipper Data structure

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Im new to Haskell. I was reading through the Zipper data structure from learnyouahaskell.com . I am simply not able to understand when and why would I use a Zipper for trees or lists or anything

Comment: A use case not present in the answer @Thilo linked, is [`xml-conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit).

Comment: This (Elm) presentation has a nice use case for zippers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcgmSRJHu_8

Comment: I found http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/04/you-could-have-invented-zippers/ useful: updating an immutable tree with bidirectional nodes requires rewriting the entire tree. Updating an immutable tree represented as a zipper only requires updating one node.